# Ruby on rails errors on command “rails server“

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

Here is my stack trace:

[image: Rails server stack trace]

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install nodejs

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Thank you very much.You helped me save time.

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)